# std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator skip folder and its subfolder

Tags: c++, std, c++17, std-filesystem

I need to recursively search files into one directory and its subdirectory but I want to exclude one path (with its files and subdirectory) from the search.

I'm using `std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` and `pop()` modifier but it doesn't work. Where I'm wrong?

```
void search(const char* pathToSearch,const char* pathToExclude){        
    std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iterator(pathToSearch);
    for (auto& p : iterator) {
        if (p.path() == std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry(pathToExclude).path()) iterator.pop();
        if (fs::is_directory(p)) continue; //exclude directory from output
        else std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the range-based for loop operates on a hidden copy of `iterator`, not `iterator` itself. If you need to manipulate the iterator being used for iteration, you need the regular `for`:

```
for(decltype(iterator) end; iterator != end; ++iterator) {
   // ...
}
```

Second, `pop` means "go up one level", but when you compared `iterator->path()` to your excluded path, your iteration hasn't descended into the directory so `pop` won't do the right thing. Instead, use `disable_recursion_pending`.